# How to make a multiple line, left-aligned UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, uialertview

I am interested in making a left-aligned UIAlertView with several lines like a bulletin list that would look like the following:

- line 1
- line 2
- line 3

Here's what I have so far:

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"How to use buttons"
                                   message: @"line 1. line 2, line 3 "
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

I also want to change the color of the alert view to red.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Bullets are represented by the unicode code 0x2022. I got it to work like this using "\n" for new lines:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
            initWithTitle: @"How to use buttons"
            message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C line 1.\n %C line 2,\n %C line 3", (unichar) 0x2022, (unichar) 0x2022, (unichar) 0x2022];
            delegate: nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

That should work for the bullets.

For the left alignment, do this:

```
NSArray *subViewArray = alertView.subviews;
for(int x = 0; x < [subViewArray count]; x++){

    //If the current subview is a UILabel...
    if([[[subViewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
}
```

So in summary:

- "\n" for displaying **new lines**.
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C Line n", (unichar) 0x2022];` for the **bullets**.
- For the **alignment**, iterate through the subviews of the alert view and identify which subviews are subclasses of `UILabel`. Then change the text alignment of the labels to left alignment using `label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft`.
- After you do **all** this, then you can call `[alert show];`.

Comment: hello, it is now Center Aligned. I want left aligned with bulletins. If you have longer texts, you will see they are center aligned

Comment: Have a plus one from me for your detailed answer

Comment: no, almost all my questions are good quality, but now I got this "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more." Do do have experience about this?

Comment: @qegal : I just added one line, working perfectly: ((UILabel*)[[alert subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

Comment: Also, when doing bullets, you need to typecast the hex code to prevent Xcode from displaying a warning: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C Line n", (unichar) 0x2022]`

Comment: a typo NSArray *subViewArray = alertView.subViews; should be subviews

Comment: @pasawaya The code for left alignment does not seem to work. First of all, I assume you meant NSArray *subViewArray = alert.subviews; because alertView.subviews does not exist. Second, when I place this code after the initialization of alert, the subViewArray has zero objects. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pasawaya the code for left alignment does not to work on iOS 9

Comment: This code does not work in Xamarin. `foreach(var n in alert.Subviews) if (n is UILabel) {...}`

Answer (score 4):

to align left:

```
 NSArray *subviewArray = alert.subviews;
for(int x = 0; x < [subviewArray count]; x++){

    if([[[subviewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:x];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    }
```

To show a red background behind alert view:

```
alert.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Taken from qegals code and adjusted. @ DavidNg Can I sugest you accept his answer and perhaps plus one the people who have helped you here

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the \ and not the normal /.

alt + shift + 7 (on my Keyboard)

\n

That should do it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new line by inserting `\n` into your message. For example:

```
@"line 1.\nline 2,\nline 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the new line and text alignment prefer the **@qegal's** answer that one is perfect but if you like to change the color or customize the alert view I got one great class to use instead of system's alert view just check [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/CustomAlertView) out, this will definitely works. even it will also helps you to get multi-lined message with alignment and bulleted list.

If you found any problem with using it ask for help, I will surely help you out.

Happy Coding :)